# How to Print an Embeded PDF of a webpage using a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So, i am basically making a chrome extension that prints the Embeded PDF of a webpage.
but the problem is it does prints an embeded PDF of a webpage

i have tried this approach:-

`let pdfEmbedElem= document.querySelector( 'embed[type="application/pdf"]' ) pdfEmbedElem.print()`

but the `print()` is always undefined

i am expecting a approach that just works haha

Comment: you should interact with the PDF viewer that's rendering the PDF.

Comment: iis there any workaround or hack or anything in this world that can allow me to print a pdf in from a chrome extension.

1. i have tried to send a mouse click event on a specific co-ordinate to click the print button but didn;t workeed

2. i have tried doing sending a keyboard evnt of "Ctrl + P" to hopefully trigger Print but still didn't worked

any help would be appriciated